# Answers after fune-tuning model

Tags: python, nlp

I make fine-tuning with my model on essays like :

```
[{
        "topic": "Мы были достаточно цивилизованны, чтобы построить машину, но слишком примитивны, чтобы ею пользоваться». (Карл Краус)",
        "text": "Высказывание Карла Крауса, австрийского писателя, о том, что «мы были достаточно цивилизованны, чтобы построить машину... 
}]
```

And also when i try to make prompt like "Напиши сочинение на тему война" (Write an essay on the topic of war) my model answered like: **'_"Война и мир" \u043f\u0443. /."},{"topic":"1845_1853","text'(word and peace)'** or  **'_?¿)\u00bb \u041f\e0440\d044f, / "", ".",","text":"'**

Where is mistake?
There are my code:

```
modelpath = 'tinkoff-ai/ruDialoGPT-medium'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(modelpath)
model = AutoModelWithLMHead.from_pretrained('toodles_essays')
```

And parametrs are:

```
async def generate_response(text):
    inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt')
    generated_token_ids = model.generate(
        **inputs,
        top_k=8,
        top_p=0.65,
        num_beams=4,
        num_return_sequences=1,
        do_sample=True,
        no_repeat_ngram_size=2,
        temperature=1.5,
        repetition_penalty=1.5,
        length_penalty=1.0,
        eos_token_id=50256,
        pad_token_id=50256,
        max_new_tokens=40
    )
    response = [tokenizer.decode(sample_token_ids) for sample_token_ids in generated_token_ids][0]
    return response
```

I need to writing an essay by my model, how can ii do it?